# how to add inputField in a PageBlockTable for Custom Object Using Custom Controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I have a custom object and I wanna add multiple records of the Custom Object using Custom Controller

I have written the Controller logic  , I have created a wrapper class in Controller and I am passing the same to the visual force page , it is working fine.

However, the problem is I am unable to feed the values in the fields to save the record  in the visual force page.

Can anybody look at the logic and do the needful thanks In Advance ???

```
<!-- controller="addMultipleBooksToLibraryController" -->

<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="addMultipleBooksExtension">
<apex:form id="formId">
<apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listBook}" var="b" >
       <apex:column headerValue="NAME" value="{!b.Name}">
       </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="AUTHOR" value="{!b.Author}" ></apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton value="Add one more Book" action="{!addBook}" rerender="pageBlock" />
<apex:commandButton value="Save your Records" action="{!saveBookRecords}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

..................................................................

```
public with sharing class addMultipleBooksExtension {
    public list<myWrapper> listBook{get;set;}
    Public myWrapper bk ;
    public addMultipleBooksExtension() {
        myWrapper wrap = new myWrapper();
        listBook = new list<myWrapper> ();
        listBook.add(wrap);
    }
    public void addBook(){
        myWrapper wrap1 = new myWrapper();
        listBook.add(wrap1);
    }
    public void saveBookRecords(){
    }
    //  Decide what you wanna display on the page 
    class myWrapper {
        public String Name{get;set;}
        public String Author{get;set;}
    } 
}
```

Comment: your `saveBookRecords()` method does nothing. DML statement will be needed; there are no variables of any SObject in your controller.

Comment: Just adding to above comment , after you have DML in SaveBooKrecords() method, if you want to display the records you have added , you may want to create another pageblocktable with same wrapped list and partially refersh/ rerender that pageblock.

Comment: What is your custom object you are using?Please specify as i cant see any variables of any custom object.